# How can I fabricate missing interval records?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that consists of changes that occur in irregular time intervals.

For example

```
ID   YEAR ADDRESS
ABC  2015 123 Meadow Ln
ABC  2017 66 Sycamore ST
EFG  2017 99 Morris St
```

I want to create a balanced series of time intervals, as follows -

```
ABC  2015 123 Meadow Ln
ABC  2016 123 Meadow Ln
ABC  2017 66 Sycamore ST
ABC  2018 66 Sycamore ST
ABC  2019 66 Sycamore ST
EFG  2017 99 Morris St
EFG  2018 99 Morris St
EFG  2019 99 Morris St
```

In what I assume is a second step, I would like to propagate backwards as well..

So....

```
ID   YEAR  ADDRESS
ABC  2013  123 Meadow Ln
ABC  2014  123 Meadow Ln
ABC  2015  123 Meadow Ln
ABC  2016  123 Meadow Ln
ABC  2017  66 Sycamore ST
ABC  2018  66 Sycamore ST
ABC  2019  66 Sycamore ST
EFG  2013  99 Morris St
EFG  2014  99 Morris St
EFG  2015  99 Morris St
EFG  2016  99 Morris St
EFG  2017  99 Morris St
EFG  2018  99 Morris St
EFG  2019  99 Morris St
```

And finally, as I do this, I would also like to be able to keep track of real/fake records, the final DataFrame probably should look like --

```
ID   YEAR  ADDRESS         ORIGINAL_RECORD
ABC  2013  123 Meadow Ln   False
ABC  2014  123 Meadow Ln   False
ABC  2015  123 Meadow Ln   True
ABC  2016  123 Meadow Ln   False
ABC  2017  66 Sycamore ST  True
ABC  2018  66 Sycamore ST  False
ABC  2019  66 Sycamore ST  False
EFG  2013  99 Morris St    False
EFG  2014  99 Morris St    False
EFG  2015  99 Morris St    False
EFG  2016  99 Morris St    False
EFG  2017  99 Morris St    True
EFG  2018  99 Morris St    False
EFG  2019  99 Morris St    False
```

Is there a straightforward/idiomatic way of doing this?

Edit: I updated the examples to include an ID column.

Answer (score 3):

Use [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) in conjunction with [fillna(method=...)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

```
def fill_missing_years(df):
    return (
        df.set_index("YEAR")
        .reindex(range(2013, 2020))
        .assign(
            ORIGINAL_RECORD=lambda x: ~x.isna().any(axis=1)
        )  # set ORIGINAL_RECORD flag
        .fillna(method="ffill")
        .fillna(method="bfill")
        .reset_index()
    )

df.groupby("id").apply(fill_missing_years).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Note on ORIGINAL_RECORD:

`reindex` fills new rows with `NaN` values, so we can use `isna()` method to calculate a mask nan/not-nan. In general case it returns a boolean DataFrame:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [None, 1, None], "b": [2, None, None]})
>>> df.isna()
True  False
False True
True  True
```

So we have to collapse this DataFrame into a single column using `any()` or `all()` along the first axis:

```
>>> df.isna().all(axis=1)
False
False
True
```

Finally, we use inversion ('~') to return True if all columns in the row are not `nan`.

Comment: Ohhh! Very cool. 

How would I do it if there were another variable, like an ID, and I wanted this to be within the id group? Is that a transform operation?

Comment: Do you need groupby + reindex inside the group? If so, than you need a `groupby('ID').apply(lambda df: df.set_index("YEAR").reindex()...)` Could you provide an example?

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: I've made a small change to ORIGINAL_RECORD calculation (added `.any(axis=1)` with explanation). The rest of the code is untouched. Now it should work with any number of columns.

Comment: the isna bit is clever. Is it impossible to use transform because of reset_index?

Comment: I get the error, cannot reindex from duplicate axis. I tweaked the example to something that I hope will cause the error.

Comment: @JoshuaFarina, yeah, this is because of duplicated year. So, you need a `groupby` here.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: I was trying to figure out the groupby. I think I was stuck on how to reset the in-group index.

Comment: You probably need a `reset_index(drop=True)` after `groupby().apply()`. You can also use `groupby(..., as_index=False)` to reset in-group index.